# Get xpath sibling text value - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

**Requirement:**

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[7]/div/div/div/div/p/b - Contains word "TITLE"
/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[8]/div/div/div/div/p   - Contains "This is my description"
```

Actual HTML:

```
    <div class="secadvheading section">
   <div class="section-custom">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <p class="mt-15"><b>TITLE</b></p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="paragraphText parbase section">
<div class="section-custom ">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>This is my desciption</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Question:**
How to get text content paragraph text after "TITLE" div?

Tried

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'TITLE')]/following-sibling::p")
```

didn't worked. I may have multiple "TITLE in same page" how can i gracefully look for TITILE div (multiple elements) and get the description for the same?

Comment: XPaths look a bit confusing to me. Could you also post small HTML snippet?

Comment: @AlexandraDudkina Added html for the same

Comment: try with:  //p[contains(text(),'TITLE')]//following::p - if this is the only next existent "p", it will find it

Comment: Nope. didn't worked. tried $x("//p[contains(text(),'TITLE')]//following::p") returns []
​
length: 0

Comment: It would be good if you provide more html content and mentioned your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go out of TITLE's node first--go to ancestor node the use following-sibling. Try this:

```
//b[text()='TITLE']/ancestor::div[@class='secadvheading section']/following-sibling::div[@class='paragraphText parbase section']//p
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. have altered a bit, like this, $x("//*[contains(text(),'TITLE')][0]/ancestor::div[@class='secadvheading section']/following-sibling::div[@class='paragraphText parbase section']//p")[0].text